# Average data explorer results before plotting them

Tags: support, data-explorer, statistics

I'm making investigative queries that are not very effective. The last query I did is seeking correlation between post length and view count:

```
SELECT ViewCount, Sum(DataLength(Body))/count(*) FROM Posts WHERE Body IS NOT NULL AND PostTypeId=1 GROUP BY ViewCount ORDER BY ViewCount
```

The thing is that there's a lot of noise in [the result](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/255838#graph):

[image: view count by post length]

I'd prefer to average it on some range, say 1000 and get a curve:

[image: average values in graph]

Could this be done in the query itself?

Answer (score 1):

I'm bad at SQL, so I don't know if this is the "right" way to do this, but it works:

```sql
DECLARE @bin_size int = 1000

SELECT
  i.[BinLower],
  AVG(i.[Y]) AS [AvgY]
FROM
  (
  SELECT 
    CEILING((p.ViewCount - 1)/@bin_size) * @bin_size AS [BinLower], 
    Sum(DataLength(p.Body))/count(*) AS [Y]
  FROM 
    Posts AS p
  WHERE 
    p.Body IS NOT NULL 
    AND p.PostTypeId = 1 
  GROUP BY 
    p.ViewCount 
  ) AS i
GROUP BY
  i.[BinLower]
ORDER BY
  i.[BinLower]
```

[image: a graph]

[Here it is on SEDE.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/256170/query-for-tomas-zato#graph)

Probably still not as smooth as you might like (for SO, anyway), but you can futz with the `@bin_size` parameter and see if that helps. Maybe add a cutoff like

```sql
WHERE i.[BinLower] < 1000000
```

to get rid of noise in the right tail. Being smarter about the binning function (e.g. narrower for low view counts, wider for higher view counts) would also probably help.